# How to cancel datagrid edit

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a view that uses a usercontrol that contains a datagrid. The requirements for the view state that if a user deletes the value out of the "Customer Name" column then leaves the cell, don't commit the edit and change the value back to its original value - i.e. don't allow blank customer names. The usercontrol is shared code and is used between multiple applications. The edit cancellation requirement is specifically for the view mentioned above (not all applications that use the usercontrol). How do i detect the value  for the Customer Name cell has been deleted and cancel the edit if the value is empty?

Answer (score 4):

You can handle `CellEditEnding` - its Occurs before a cell edit is committed or canceled. Here you can validate current value of the cell, and if it satisfy your condition[s] you can do what ever you want. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)

---

**Edit:**
Its my suggestions, but I can't approve it.
You can get your new value via `e.Row.Item`, and cast it to object you put on `DataGrid`.
Another way is cast `sender` object right way to get access for new cell value.

+1 is to DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs.EditingElement. Its FrameworkElement, and I think you know what it is (probably TextBox, or something else).

also I think you know what you should to do!

Comment: yeah that's where my code will go. the problem is, I don't know the recently entered value of the cell since the commit hasn't happened. I can get the "old" value - the one that was just erased but i don't know what the user is attempting to change it to. I think inside the CellEditEnding event, i need to drill down to the textbox inside the cell and look at its text property to see what the user is attempting to change it to. Not sure how i would do that though.